# Can't run memory access checking on Solaris sample project

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

When I run memory access checking on the [sample project](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/solaris-studio-samples-1408618.html) provided by Oracle with Oracle Solaris Studio, I ran into this error message:

> Please re-config Project memorychecks to be compiled with Oracle Solaris Studio12 Update 3 or higher.

I tried to change the compiler from gcc to cc, but the problem still exists.

Is it possible that the problem is with the Makefile?

Comment: It's possible it's the Makefile.  More details would help.

Comment: OBJS = memtest.o init_array.o init_array_loc.o  \
       print_list.o free_list.o bld_cust_list.o

CCFLAGS = -c -g -DSTRDUP
LDFLAGS = -g

#gc_memtest : $(OBJS)
#  CC -o gc_memtest -lgc_dbg -g $(OBJS)

memtest : $(OBJS)
  cc $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o memtest

Comment: The details could be seen in the sample project